# showing taskpane on a Mac

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Can someone confirm whether using a taskpane add-in is supported on Outlook 2016 **for Mac**?  I need something that always displays on the right, not under the email body.  Ideally pinnable, but also curious if non-pinnable is supported too.

Answer (score 1):

- Taskpane add-ins for Outlook 2016 on Mac are supported (Source: [Pinnable Taskpane in Outlook 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/) look up at the last comments).
- Add-in Commands are supported for Outlook on Mac (Source: [Add-in Commands in OWA and Outlook on the Mac](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/20/add-in-commands-in-owa-and-outlook-on-the-mac/)).
- Pinnable taskpanes are currently only supported by Outlook 2016 for Windows (Source: [Implement a pinnable taskpane in Outlook](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/pinnable-taskpane)).